# SwiftUI - Append to Empty Array

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to figure where I am going wrong.

Fetching results from `CoreData` and need to append to an empty array.

I get the following error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

This occurs when doing `self.pictureObject.append(word.englishName)`

I have tried interpolating the value without success.

```
struct gameBeginV2: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @FetchRequest(entity: WordList.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var wordList: FetchedResults<WordList>
    @State private var pictureObject: [String]

    func processDictionary() -> some View {
        ForEach((wordList), id: \.self) { word in
            self.pictureObject.append(word.englishName)
            //Text(word.englishName)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

Without knowing enough about what you actually want `processDictionary(...)` to do.

Your function needs to look something like this:

```
func processDictionary(word: WordList) -> some View {
    self.pictureObject.append(word.englishName)

    return ForEach(self.wordList) { word in
        Text(word.englishName)
    }
}
```

OR even something like this:

```
func processDictionary(word: WordList) -> some View {
    self.pictureObject.append(word.englishName)

    return ForEach(self.pictureObject, id: \.self) { englishName in
        Text(englishName)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry I should have explained it's not a class but information held in CoreData. Entity Name: WordList with attributes englishName: String, urhoboName: string. Thanks

Comment: @ufookoro Provide more context and the actual class in the question not in comments.

Comment: Thanks I will try and implement your solution. Kind Regards

Comment: Just tested this morning, and yes it worked. Thank you.

Comment: if work then pls put a mark for person who give a solution. Its give them more motivation

Comment: Hello, I have look around the page and cannot see where I can indicate as issue resolved.